# add component inside ActionListener on a for or while loop CodenameOne

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, codenameone

I have an action listener like this:

```
Form hi = new Form("test");
bbb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        while(f < 10){
            hi.addComponent(new Label("test"));
            f++;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it skips all the `addComponent`. Why is this so?

Comment: `"i don't understand why it skip all that addComponent"` -- we don't either given only a small snippet of poorly formatted code. What is Form for instance? Where do you display this Form (set it visible)? Please create and post an [mcve].

Comment: I've tried to edit your code so that it is formatted correctly and thus more readable. You've been here long enough, and have enough rep points, that you should already know to do this yourself, right?

Comment: i know, i have short time and i'm working saturday and sunday... sorry if i didn't formatted well

Comment: f's value is not clear. it can be bigger than 10 and if then, it does not go into while loop

Comment: i solved anyway...i was doubting that i couldn't add item dynamically on codename One...anyway the f started from 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `revalidate()` or `animateLayout()` to the end of the method. Otherwise Codename One assumes you are still adding components.